# How to switch copy mode between text and html with React

Tags: reactjs, forms, text, frontend, html-mode

I want to implement the input form which can be switched between plain text and html mode by users with React.
However I have no idea how to do this.
Please give me some hints e.g. sample code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices based on your desire !

1. If plain text and html mode styles are completely different, you can create two separate components and trigger which one to show by a simple `useState()`
2. If you just want to disable the html input in plain text mode , you can disable the input and give it your own style, you should again set the `disabled` props equal to a boolean state and trigger that state by a button